# Perl & LWP: getstore() will only save a file if I don't specify a directory

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm probably missing something simple but I have got getstore() running perfectly to save a ".png" file to my Windows PC as follows:

```
getstore("$url","$filename");
```

That works a treat and downloads the file perfectly to the directory containing the Perl script.  However if I try saving it to a subfolder of "newdir" nothing downloads:

```
getstore("$url","newdir\\$filename");
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong here or how I could debug?  I tried printing the directory and it looks good:

```
print "newdir\\$filename";
```

However there's nothing in "newdir" once the script runs.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "to the directory containing the Perl script" is incorrect; it downloads it to the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is opened using `open(my $fh, ">", $arg)`, where `$arg` contains the value you pass. As such, it will most definitely accept relative paths.

```
>dir /b newdir

>perl -MLWP::Simple=getstore -e"getstore('http://stackoverflow.com/', 'newdir\\so.html')"

>dir /b newdir
so.html
```

Maybe `$filename` isn't valid (e.g. ends with a newline). Maybe the current directory isn't what you think it is (it can be a directory other than the one containing the script). Maybe the user as which the script is executing doesn't have access to the directory. You should be able to get more information using:

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $response = $ua->request($request, "newdir\\$filename");
die($response->status_line)
   if !$response->is_success;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried using relative and full paths but the only way I can get it to download is by not specifying a path at all.  The first thing you suggested worked fine for me too.  The second one produced no output until I removed the condition on the last line and then I got "200 OK at script.pl line 123, <> line 5."  Still no file though (even after a full HD search).  It's from a site I had to log in to first using WWW::Mechanize, but as I say it downloads fine if I just don't specify a directory.

Comment: FIXED.  You've cracked it.  It was indeed an unchomped new line character.  I didn't spot it and I'm blaming Windows's stupid tiny Command Prompt terminal screen! ;)  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can make the terminal larger